# PHP Script to Send HTTPS Value to Browser

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, https

I have a form that collects a user’s favorite color.  After the favorite color is submitted through the form, I need to run a PHP script which posts that value to the browser in the following manner:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue`

I should add that `mywebsite.com` is outside of the website where the favorite color form exists.

This would be the case where the favorite color submitted was blue.

After this sample URL is called in the browser it would output a JSON array stating:

`{favoritecolorid: 123456}`

I would then need to pull this value and insert it in a MySQL database table.

So… with this being the case I am looking for a simple PHP script to handle both the posting of the HTTPS value as well as the database update.  Any suggestions?

Comment: not really sire what your asking but at a guess `header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue');`

Comment: Please clarify: you post favourite color to a page on your server. The page should 1. store the color; 2. post to another domain; 3. JSON object returned. Correct?

Comment: @cyadvert yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understood you want to do 3 things in the page you post to.

1. store the color
2. post to another domain
3. output JSON

Points 1 and 3 are not the problem.

For point 2 I would suggest to use curl().

If you do not care about the response, then just call `curl('https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue')`

If you do care about the response, then you do it with all the returns...

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?favoritecolor=blue');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$Response = curl_exec($curl);       
curl_close($curl);
```

`$Response` will have page return.

Depending on your server settings you might need to play with `curl_setopt()` fields.

Comment: **NEVER, EVER DISABLE PEER VERIFICATION.** The data you transfer using this method is readily visible to and can be modified by a MitM attacker. It is not safe.